# how to replace hardcoded value with database data in an array in react

Tags: reactjs, database, async-await

I have a variable that has some hard-coded value

```
  export const test = [
 {
id: 1,
label: '20201127-043000',
value: '20201127-043000',
},
{
id: 2,
label: '20201120-043000',
value: '20201120-043000',
},


];
```

Now I have a table in the database that has the same data. I want to replace this hardcoded data with database data.

```
 export const getLatestData = async() =>
  {
    const url = `${testdb.serverUrl}/findLatest`;
    const res = await axios.get(url).then(res => res);
    return res.data;
  }
```

Now I will use the test variables in the future for getting the first data, finding some value, etc.

```
 export const getValueByLabel = label => find(test, { label }).value;
```

Not sure how can I do that. May I get some help?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

In case `getLatestData` is giving you the same data, then just replace the array with new data array.

```
getLatestData().then(latest => data=latest);
```

But I don't think so you just need that. You have tagged `react`.
If you are using this array, then tell me how you are using it.

Comment: test const holds a hard-coded array and I need to replace this hard-coded array with database data and I will use the test const for many functionalities. say, I can search for a particular label in the array. Does it answer your question?

Comment: okay, to make it simple, I am providing an answer then

Answer (score 0):

```
const [data, setData] = useState([...test])
getLatestData().then(latestData => setData([...latestData]));
```

This will work if you are using [Functional Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)